# does libpython exist under win32 environment?

Tags: python, ipython

I'm looking for a "libpython" for  Python3 32 bits on Windows.
I don't find any,
I only see a "64bit" build on "http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#libpython"

Does it exist ? 
Does it need to exist ?

(discussion here :https://github.com/jakebolewski/pyjulia/pull/3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mingw32 compatible link libraries for the 32 bit Python DLLs are included with the official 32 bit [CPython installers](https://www.python.org/downloads/). There should be a `libpython??.a` file in the `sys.prefix\libs\` directory. The `libmsvcr??.a` libraries should be included with the mingw distribution.

Comment: ah, ok. Thank you Christoph. Now I see the first one :  "python-3.4.1\libs\libpython34.a".  but libmsvcr??.a is still hidden to me.

Comment: The `libmsvcr??.a` libraries should be included with the mingw distribution, e.g. in `C:\MinGW\lib`

Comment: ok, now I see I have  "python-3.4.1\libs\libpython34.a",   tools\mingw32\lib\libmsvcrt.a and tools\mingw32\lib\libmsvcrtd.a . Thank you very much , and my "Failed to initialize PyCall package" from Julia is not explained by these missing libraries. but they are not uploaded by WINRPM of Julia in its .julia\v0.3\WinRPM\deps\usr\i686-w64-mingw32, so maybe the problem is there.

Comment: For Python 3.4 you would need `libmsvcr100.a`

Comment: Thanks. I've got it. I'm more disturb by seeing a quite different set of .dll in my mingw (32) install and in the one of WinRPM of Julia.

Comment: I've got a "libintl-8.dll" which is v0.18.3.0 and size 473k from Mingw, and 0.18.1 and a mere 107k from Julia. and zlib1.dll is v1.2.8 in both case but 128k from mingw and 82k from WinRPM. Mingw has libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll, but WinRPM has libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll . I may create strange mixes by having both in the path

Comment: I can't find the library with python 3.8? Am I missing something? There's only python38.dll